# Проблемы с TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Использовал руководство для начала работы с TypeScript на Node
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript

Установил через

`npm i --save node-telegram-bot-api`

и сделал импорт ему:

`import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';`.

И не понимаю, почему нет подсказок после того, как начинаю использовать его и сама строка подсвечивается, как

`Свойство "TelegramBot" объявлено, но его значение не было прочитано.`

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А какие подсказки нужны? И ошибка же довольно понятно описана: вы импортировали переменную, но ничего с ней не делаете

Comment: Допустим, чтобы использовать бота дальше. То есть создаю инстанс бота и после него хочу использовать bot.sendMessage(), а он не подсвечивает, что можно использовать после bot.